# CSS first-child pseudo class with unordered list (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I am trying to render a background color on the list item that is the first child of the unordered list.

HTML structure is as follows

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and to apply the background color on the first child element I did

```
.nav-collapse > .nav:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

It renders orange background to all list items.
I've played with slight variations but it doesn't make difference.

```
.nav-collapse > ul.nav:first-child
.nav-collapse > ul:first-child
```

[Here is the Demo](http://jsbin.com/ImoBOza/2/edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
.nav > li:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WgxCY/)

You were trying to style the first `.nav` item - which there is only one of. Simply change it to style the first `li` that is a direct child of `.nav`.

If you want to be more specific use:

```
.nav-collapse > .nav > li:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways, try this too

```
ul.nav > li:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
}
```